# Is Python optimized (to a certain extent) automatically at runtime?

Tags: python

I'm just curious to know. For example, if I wanted to check if a number is even, either of these will work:

`# values are True if even, False if odd

even_masked = not (number & 0x1)

even_modulo = (number%2 == 0)`

They both do the same thing but the first method is much faster in terms of clock cycles. In C you can set the compiler to make optimizations like this for you, but does the Python interpreter do something similar?

Comment: The cost of doing a modulo is dwarfed by the overhead in Python's bytecode interpreter, including the pointer indirection needed to even get the value of `number`, the typecheck on it, and the refcounting :)

Answer (score 0):

The bytecode of these two functions are different, thanks to the [`dis`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) module:

```
>>> def test(number):
...     even_masked = not (number & 0x1)
...
>>> def test2(number):
...     even_modulo = (number%2 == 0)
...
>>> dis.dis(test)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (number)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              6 BINARY_AND
              7 UNARY_NOT
              8 STORE_FAST               1 (even_masked)
             11 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(test2)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (number)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              6 BINARY_MODULO
              7 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
             10 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             13 STORE_FAST               1 (even_modulo)
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             19 RETURN_VALUE
```

But... we can see that there's a very few difference between the two methods:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("even_modulo = (number%2 == 0)", setup="number=1", number=100000000)
11.886679887771606
>>> timeit.timeit("even_masked = not (number & 0x1)", setup="number=1", number=100000000)
11.225641965866089
```

So keep your scripts readable instead of making this kind of optimization. The time you will loose at understanding the first line will be way more important than the time saved in execution, even if your script is used million times :-)

Answer (score 0):

The [`dis`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) module shows the instructions Python does under the hood

For `not (number & 0x1)`:

```
          0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (number)
          3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
          6 BINARY_AND
          7 UNARY_NOT
          8 POP_TOP
```

For `(number%2 == 0)`:

```
          0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (number)
          3 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
          6 BINARY_MODULO
          7 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
         10 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
         13 POP_TOP
```

It seems pretty literal to the expression you gave it.